# How to make button that shows a list of options on long click, like on the Soft Keyboard

Tags: android, android-widget, android-sdk-2.1

I want to use/create a button that works like the one on the (HTC Desire) Soft Keyboard. 
So that when you make a long click, it will show a list of options, and by sliding your finger to the left or right, you select which option you want to choose.

Example: When I hold down the "12#" button on the keyboard, it presents the 
list: [: / @ _ - ! ? '], and by sliding left or right it highlights one of these characters and chooses the selected one when I release my finger. If I just click normally, it selects the default character.

Is there such a widget in the Android SDK, or can anyone give a hint on how to implement such a component.

See screenshot: Entering text, and just long pressed the "12#" button. "!" is currently selected.

[image]

Comment: Could you edit your question and include a screenshot or two? Not all of us have a Desire.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a custom Activity with `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` (this will give it a transparent, floating dialog look).
2. Add to it a `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="horizontal"`
3. Add some button with icons to `LinearLayout`. This creates a transparent Button with an Icon and some text beneath it:

   ```
   <Button android:id="@+id/optionsButton
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
           android:text="@string/button_options_text"
           android:textColor="@color/button_text_grey"
           android:drawableTop="@drawable/button_options"
           android:drawablePadding="-5dip"
           android:background="@null"
   ```
4. Use [Button.onKeyLongPress(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html#onKeyLongPress%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) to show this Activity.